# How to concat two arrays and remove duplicates in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want concat following two arrays by removing duplicates without assigning to third variable:

```
var arr1=[{id:1,name:'AB'},{id:2,name:'CD'}];

var arr2=[{id:3,name:'EF'},{id:2,name:'CD'}];
```

I want arr1 like:

```
[{id:1,name:'AB'},{id:2,name:'CD'},{id:3,name:'EF'}]

arr1.concat(arr2);
```

Comment: Use lodash union https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#union or https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#uniqWith

Comment: you can simply loop through array which has less elements & compare with the other array . push the non-existing object to the same array to avoid usage 3rd variable..

Comment: can you help me that loop ,am tried not getting@supercool

Comment: `$.each(arr1,(i,x)=>{ if($.grep(arr2,(y)=> x.id == y.id && x.name==y.name ).length < 1)  arr2.push(x); });` something like this, hope if helps. you can use `.filter` inplace of grep in `ang`

Comment: I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60918864/4934446) an option with `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 7):

First merge two arrays then put array into a map with their ids. Then create array from map values.

```js
var arr1=[{id:1,name:'AB'},{id:2,name:'CD'}];
var arr2=[{id:3,name:'EF'},{id:2,name:'CD'}];

arr1 = arr1.concat(arr2) // merge two arrays
let foo = new Map();
for(const tag of arr1) {
  foo.set(tag.id, tag);
}
let final = [...foo.values()]
console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 6):

Can use Array [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to achieve what you want.

```js
var arr1=[{id:1,name:'AB'},{id:2,name:'CD'}];

var arr2=[{id:3,name:'EF'},{id:2,name:'CD'}];

// loop over arr2, add the elements of array2 if it doesn't exist in array1
var newArr = arr2.reduce((acc, eachArr2Elem) => {
  if (arr1.findIndex((eachArr1Elem) => eachArr1Elem.id === eachArr2Elem.id && eachArr1Elem.name === eachArr2Elem.name)  === -1) {
    acc.push(eachArr2Elem)
  }
  return acc
}, [...arr1]); // initialize the new Array with the contents of array1

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: is it possible without assigning to third variable

Comment: @madhuGoud: You also mean the variables in the callBacks? I guess No (Not in plain Javascript), Here the elements are `Objects`, there is no simple way to concat them and remove duplicates

Comment: is it possible in typescript

Comment: @madhuGoud: TypeScript is just a superset of Javascript, it is not a library. I am not clear with what you mean by the third variable. Do you want to modify any of the existing `arr1` or `arr2` with new array? Remember, something like: `arr1.concat(arr2);` is also a new reference, its just that you are not assigning it to a variable

Comment: @madhuGoud Check my solution if you want, I solved this with using map. Since your arrays have objects in it, it's not that simple. If your arrays were not objects, you could use `Set` to achieve unique array easily.

Answer (score 1):

using the `spread` operator you can flatten any amount of arrays passed to the `combineAndDeDup` method, i have also split out some logic methods for (hopefully) more readable code. i hope this helps.

```js
const arr1 = [{id:1,name:'AB'}, {id:2,name:'CD'}]
const arr2 = [{id:3,name:'EF'}, {id:2,name:'CD'}]

const flatten = a => [].concat.apply([], a)
const noDuplicateProps = (a, b) => Object.keys(a).some(k => a[k] === b[k])

const combineAndDeDup = (...arrs) => {
  
  return flatten(arrs).reduce((acc, item) => {
    const uniqueItem = acc.findIndex(i => noDuplicateProps(i, item)) === -1
    
    if (uniqueItem) return acc.concat([ item ])
    
    return acc
  }, [])
}


const deDuped = combineAndDeDup(arr1, arr2)
const megaDeDuped = combineAndDeDup(arr1, arr2, arr1, arr1, arr2, arr1)

console.log(deDuped)
console.log(megaDeDuped)
```

Comment: what to add if in case one array is empty than the result should be empty as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you like clean ES6 try this: 
Happy code :)

```js
function arrayWithNoDuplicates(array, field) {
  const arrayWithoutNoDuplicates = array.filter((value, index, self) =>
    index === self.findIndex((t) => (
      t[field] === value[field]
    ))
  )
  return arrayWithoutNoDuplicates
}

const arr1 = [{id:1,name:'AB'}, {id:2,name:'CD'}]
const arr2 = [{id:3,name:'EF'}, {id:2,name:'CD'}]

// The first param is the two merged arrays and the second the field you
// to filter by
console.log(arrayWithNoDuplicates([...arr1, ...arr2], 'id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#uniqWith) `_.uniqWith(array, [comparator])`

```
var objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];

_.uniqWith(objects, _.isEqual);
// => [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var arr1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'AB' }, { id: 2, name: 'CD' }];
  var arr2 = [{ id: 3, name: 'EF' }, { id: 3, name: 'XX' }];
  arr1.forEach(element => {
    arr2.forEach((el, idx) => {
      if (element.id === el.id || element.name === el.name) {
        delete arr2[idx]
      }
    });
  });

  let data = arr1.concat(arr2)

  // or arr1 = arr1.concat(arr2)
  // then your arr1 contains your unique array
```

data variable contains your unique array

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one liner that compares by `id`.

```
let result = arr1.concat( arr2.filter( i2 => !arr1.find( i1 => i1.id == i2.id ) ) );
```

I have modified elements to show what happens for different objects with the same `id`. Swap `arr1` with `arr2` for which array you want to keep your preferred components. There seems to be no simple way to compare objects in JavaScript, you may use `JSON.stringify` but that depends on elements order. You can try it out at https://playcode.io/new/ :

```
var arr1=[{id:1,name:'AB'},{id:2,name:'CD'}];
var arr2=[{id:3,name:'EF'},{id:2,name:'GH'}];

let result;

result = arr1.concat( arr2.filter( i2 => !arr1.find( i1 => i1.id == i2.id ) ) );

console.log('RESULT: ' + JSON.stringify(result));

result = arr1.concat(
  arr2.filter(
    i2 => !arr1.find(
      i1 => {
        console.log('I1: ' + JSON.stringify(i1) + ' I2: ' + JSON.stringify(i2));
        return i1.id == i2.id;}
        )
  )
);

console.log('RESULT: ' + JSON.stringify(result));

result = arr2.concat(
  arr1.filter(
    i1 => !arr2.find(
      i2 => {
        console.log('I1: ' + JSON.stringify(i1) + ' I2: ' + JSON.stringify(i2));
        return i1.id == i2.id;}
        )
  )
);

console.log('RESULT: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Both lodash function `unionBy` and `unionWith` can solve your problem.

If your objects has unique key, `unionBy` is the most elegant way to handle it.

```
var arr1 = [{id:1,name:'AB'},{id:2,name:'CD'}];
var arr2 = [{id:3,name:'EF'},{id:2,name:'CD'}];
var mergedWithoutDups = _.unionBy(arr1, arr2. 'id')
```

If your object has no unique key, use `unionWith` and `isEqual` instead. This will take deep comparison on all objects to remove duplicate.

```
var arr1 = [{id:1,name:'AB'},{id:2,name:'CD'}];
var arr2 = [{id:3,name:'EF'},{id:2,name:'CD'}];
var mergedWithoutDups = _.unionWith(arr1, arr2. _.isEqual)
```